# jQuery success post back to parent container

Tags: jquery, ajax, parent

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<span class="spam">
     <button class="spam_button" value="2">Spam</button>
</span>
```

I'm tring to get the response to display in the parent span, but I can't figure it out.

```
$('.spam_button').live('click', function() {
    var spam_id =$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "spam.php",
        data: "spam_id="+spam_id,
        success: function(html){
            $(this).parent().html(html);                
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to capture the element inside of your click function.  `$(this)` inside of the success callback will be referencing the `ajax()` object and not your `button`

```
$('.spam_button').live('click', function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var spam_id =$button.val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "spam.php",
        data: "spam_id="+spam_id,
        success: function(html){
            $button.parent().html(html);                
        }
    });
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/hKv85/).**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.spam_button').live('click', function() {
var $this = $(this);
var spam_id =$this.val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "spam.php",
    data: "spam_id="+spam_id,
    success: function(html){
        $this.parent().html(html);                
    }
});
```

});